# Concatenate out of SELECT in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working with an android application where I need to search my database by full name, I am currently using this, which results in a list with the IDs and with FullName:

```
    SELECT _id, name || ' ' || lastname AS FullName
    FROM User
    WHERE FullName LIKE "%William Jones%"
    ORDER BY FullName
```

I know that it is necessary to create the FullName table to perform the search I need, but I would like to know if it is possible to concatenate and search but omit FullName from my result, I want to obtain only ids.

I don't know if you understand what I need, but I want something like that

```
    FullName = name || ' ' || lastname
    SELECT _id
    FROM User
    WHERE FullName LIKE "%William Jones%"
    ORDER BY FullName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this code can work:
SELECT _id from user where CONCAT(name+' ',lastname) like '%William Jones%';
Then add your order by

You can concat string with the keyword CONCAT(,) or just add an '+' between your strings

Comment: In SQLite there is no CONCAT () instead you should use || to concatenate, but I'll accept your answer because the solution is to concatenate after the WHERE
`SELECT _id
FROM User
WHERE name || ' ' || lastname LIKE "%William Jones%"
ORDER BY name`